# merge conflict using msbuild sonarquberunner

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

As a part of code quality we run `svn update` followed by `msbuild.exe "project.sln" /t:Build /m:1 /clp:ErrorsOnly"` and thereafter `msbuild sonarqube runner`. Few times I receive error mentioned below and upon investigating code checkout folder finds a `merge conflict`. As am only using `svn update` what would be the cause of same **to be noted that on revert project gets executed fine and there are no conflicts in svn repo**

**ERROR LOG**

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.24720.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4381,5): error MSB3541: Files has invalid value "<<<<<<< .mine". Illegal characters in path. [D:\SNRProjs\Scheduler.Business.csproj]

Comment: I guess this could be due to SCM plugin, I've disabled sonar property for plugin enable/disable and will watch for sometime for this error to vanish

Comment: you doesn't seem to use the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild (see http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) which is the only supported way to analyze Visual Studio Solution.

Comment: Using same only, this problem appears sometimes like once in a month. Reason is not know, full revert of code with svn update solves the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in comments by [Freddy - SonarSource Team](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417065/freddy-sonarsource-team) worked for me. Use of new *Sonarqube Scanner for MSBUILD* required.